# Почему консервы всегда во множественном числа?

Tags: лексика

Ножницы, штаны - это понятно, они все имеют парные детали. А вот что насчет консервов? Почему они тоже не бывают в единственном числе?

Answer (score 1):

Консервы - множественная совокупность (слово относится к группе названий материалов или их отходов и названий  вещества:консервы, духи, опилки, сливки, обои, хлопья, щи)
Консервы = консервированные овощи, фрукты, кусочки рыбы или мяса. Один кусочек тоже в сочетании с чем-то - маслом. уксусом и т.д.Получается совокупность многих ингредиентов.

Comment: Дело не в совокупности ингредиентов. Это просто несчётное слово. Как _пшено_ или _гуано_. Правильнее вопрос, почему оно сложилось в "консервЫ", а не в какое-нибудь "консервА". Вероятно, причина в языке-источнике.

Answer (score 0):

Консервы - это сокращенная запись словосочетания "консервированные продукты", которые противопоставлены продуктам натуральным. Таким образом, слово обозначает вид (класс) продуктов и поэтому употребляется во множественном числе.